# symfony - custom form and updating records with embedForm

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm having a small problem with `embedForm` using doctrine and SF1.4

I have created an module, that a user can edit/create/delete users from a specific group using sfDoctrineGuard

The form is simply a custom form named `manufacturerForm.class.php` and it extends `sfGuardUserAdminForm`

```
class manaufacturerForm extends sfGuardUserAdminForm
{
 public function configure()
 {
     $form = new sfGuardUserProfileForm();
     $this->embedForm('profile', $form);

     unset($this['firstname'], //this field is in sfGuardUserProfile is shown in form
           $this['user_id'],   //this field is in sfGuardUserProfile is shown in form
           $this['is_super_admin'], //this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
           $this['is_admin'], // this filed is in sfGuardUser is not shown
           $this['permissions_list'], //this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
           $this['groups_list']);//this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
  }
}
```

You can see i am embedding the `sfGuardUserProfileForm` inside my `manufacturerForm`.

I have 2 problems, the `sfGuardUserProfile` has fields that I don't want to display for this particular form, such as:
`firstname, lastname, email_new, created_at, updated_at`, but I can't seem to unset them as they still display.

Note, that this admin module does not have a `generator.yml` file. I'm doing all of this in `editSuccess.php` and using a `_form.php` partial.

My other problem is, when I edit an existing user and save all is well. The problem comes with when I try to edit as I get the following:

`An object with the same "user_id" already exist.` - this is for the `user_id` field in sfGuardUserProfile, the same goes for the `email_new` field. I get `An object with the same "email_new" already exist.`

1) How do I unset the fields that I don't need?

2) Do I need to overwrite any doSave(), updateObject(), saveEmbeddedForms() methods to stop the last problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the fields from the embedded form you need to do this within the form `sfGuardUserProfileForm`. This is because the fields are read only when embedded into the `manufacturerForm`.

If you need to remove custom fields from the `sfGuardUserProfileForm` that you normally wouldn't do, simply extend the class, remove the fields there and embed the new extended form.

When you are embedding the form you need to pass in the existing sfGuardUserPofile object.

```
class manaufacturerForm extends sfGuardUserAdminForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $form = new manaufacturerProfileForm($this->getObject()->getProfile());
        $this->embedForm('profile', $form);
    }
}


class manaufacturerProfileForm extends sfGuardUserProfileForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
        unset($this['firstname'], //this field is in sfGuardUserProfile is shown in form
              $this['user_id'],   //this field is in sfGuardUserProfile is shown in form
              $this['is_super_admin'], //this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
              $this['is_admin'], // this filed is in sfGuardUser is not shown
              $this['permissions_list'], //this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
              $this['groups_list']);//this field is in sfGuardUser is not shown
     }
```

Comment: Ok, but I have multiple 'users' so to speak, `manufacturers`, `suppliers` each needing different fields from the `sfGuardUserProfileForm class. What class is my manaufacturerForm class extending? Same goes for my supplierForm class? I still need some of the fields from sfGuardUser and also additional ones from sfGuardUserProfile. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried the code and received: `Unknown record property / related component "sf_guard_user_profile" on "sfGuardUser"`. What does this mean? I'm pretty new with doctrine. Thanks

Comment: It maybe just getProfile() instead of getSfGuardUserProfile()